# Is my account broken?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, moderators, beta

I just got off a question ban. I asked a question got up votes but I've been banned again. What did I do wrong??? There must be some mistake or glitch. Please don't make me wait another 6 months to ask another question!

[Which is the best extendable pole?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24136/which-is-the-best-extendable-pole)

Comment: I have no idea. I'd give it time. The question has a positive score, so let it be and see if it updates in a day or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question bans are controlled by the algorithms of StackExchange.  Individual site moderators have ***zero*** control regarding question bans.  Likewise, site mods are given very few details about what triggers a Q-ban or what sets the duration of the ban.

Looking at your question history, including the deleted questions, should give you a rough approximation of how the system views the quality of your contributions.  It's not an overall positive impression.

And while this is pure speculation, I wouldn't be surprised to hear that the system would trigger a fresh ban based upon the content of a new question as it was being written.  If Wasabi says that you weren't banned, then it was likely temporarily lifted.  But as of the writing of this answer, you are currently Q-banned.  I don't know what happened between now and when Wasabi looked at your account.

Looking at your most recent question, you have four edits for relatively trivial changes.  You *really* need to work on refining your questions before you click on submit.  Constant refining makes it look like you're trying to artificially bump your question, and the SE algorithms will punish that sort of behavior.

All of this boils down to your needing to acknowledge that you have had many poor submissions to this site; research your questions to understand why they were a poor fit; and then be patient for the rate limiting algorithms to lift the ban.

Comment: It was instant right after I posted the question. I thought if that question had a positive up votes it would be lifted all the way but that didn't happen. And the questions are all over a year old. I do understand now. Who do I contact now?

Comment: @Muze You can try contacting a Community Moderator at StackExchange.  Please be aware that they have a fairly high workload, and questions regarding Q-bans tend to be ignored. https://engineering.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: For the record, I deleted my comment regarding Muze not being Q-banned. I'm pretty sure I accidentally looked at their Meta account (which obviously isn't Q-banned) instead of the main site.

Comment: @Wasabi incorrect. I have a question ban there to. Some accounts are effected this way while others are normal. I do believe there is something wrong with my account. I thought the moderators was just being overly strict on certain SE hence the outbursts on my part. Thanks and sorry for mistaking.